# How to get field lists using the OpenERP Report Designer Addon for OpenOffice / LibreOffice

Tags: reporting, openoffice.org, add-on, odoo

I want to add fields to the reports and use them in python functions and do some coding inside the reports.

I am using version 6.0.3 of OpenERP, I keep getting an empty field list.

This is what the ["add field" command](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/7_23_RAD_tools/index.html#add-a-field) on the addon should look like:

[image]

I am using the "OpenERP Report Designer" addon for OpenOffice / LibreOffice. The "Add a field" command in the OpenOffice addon does not work for me. It shows an empty field list. I tried in 6.0.3 on a linux and a windows server and also 6.0.2 on a windows server. I believe all other commands of the report designer do work.

Is there a way to make it work?

(Also see the [other question how to find out the field names by browsing the sourcecode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8636949/4794))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i encountered this same problem in my windows v6.0.3 installation and found that you need to Add Loop FIRST before you can Add Field.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess. It probably needs to know what kind of object you are looping on before it can tell what fields are available.